# Losing array pointer value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am creating a function for reading numbers from file into an array. But it seems like after returning from the function, the last value is lost. Here is my code:

```c
void loadDataset(int* dataSet, int DataSetSize, char *filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( filename , "r" );

    for(int i=0; i< DataSetSize; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &dataSet[sizeof(int) * i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DataSetSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", dataSet[sizeof(int) * i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    int* ds = malloc(sizeof(int) * DataSetSize);
    loadDataset(ds, DataSetSize, DatasetFilename);

    for (int i = 0; i < DataSetSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", ds[sizeof(int) * i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

The file I am testing with contains numbers from 1 to 6. While in function `loadDataset`, the printed result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But when back in `main` function, the printed result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
0
```

What could be the problem?
I am sorry if it is something trivial I am missing, but I am not very familiar with programming in C.

Comment: Are you sure that the printed results are those?, it seems that you are skipping 4 numbers (if `sizeof(int) == 4`) on each iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &dataSet[sizeof(int) * i]);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

does not make sense. As a result of using such an expression the program has undefined behavior because there are attempts to access memory outside the allocated array.

Use instead

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &dataSet[i]);
```

or

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", dataSet + i);
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing to `fscanf(fp, "%d", &dataSet[i]);` solved my problem. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, because SO doesn't let me do it faster.